# Internationalization of .ui files in PyQt outside the method _init_

Tags: python, internationalization, pyqt

I have a view that I wish to use in different parts of my project. The view class looks as follows:

```
class GripperActionView(AbstractView):

  def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=Qt.Widget):
    super(GripperActionView, self).__init__()        
    ui_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '/ui/elements/gripper_action_view.ui')
    loadUi(ui_file, self)
```

In the initialization method a translated .ui file is loaded. When I then create a new view instance in a **init** method of some some other class, everything works fine and my view is translated. The problem is that I would like to create the view instances in other methods as well, not just the **init** method. When I do that however, my view appears untranslated. How can I work around this?

Comment: What happens if you call `ui = loadUi(ui_file)` instead? (and then add the returned `ui` object to your interface manually). Does that result in a correct translation when you call in from an arbitrary method? I think the problem is that passing `self` to `loadUI` is effectively doing widget promotion, which can only be done during `__init__` (aka before the widget object is created)

Comment: The problem that I have is that actually none of my translations work if they are not made in the constructor. I have no idea ahy that is. There is <b>ui.retranslate()</b> method that I have been using after converting my ui to a .py file but it still doesn't work.